# Increment boost array address at async read call

Tags: arrays, sockets, boost, buffer, boost-asio

is there any way I can increment the adress to a `boost::array` when passing it as an argument?

To be precise, I provide a buffer -> `boost::array<char, 4096> buffer`.

This buffer I pass to a `socket::async_read_some` call to get filled by it. Now when my `async_read_some` finishes the buffer is not necessarily full ( as I can check with `bytes_transferred` ). Now if that happens, I want to call `async_read_some` again to fill the buffer further.

Now if I pass the buffer like normal it will just overwrite the stuff in it. But I want that the functions fills the buffer at the position wherei t ended after the first call. Unfortunately I can't just pass the incremented adress `buffer+bytes_transferred` which would be possible with a normal `char*` buffer.

Here some ( simplified ) example code of what I want to do  - please presume that all stuff has been initialized and io_service is running.

```
void myClass::startRead()
{
    mySocket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer,4096)),
         boost::bind(&myClass::handle_read, shared_from_this(),
               boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}

void myClass::handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& err ,size_t bytesTransferred)
{
    if ( bytes_transferred < 4096 )
    {
            mySocket.async_read_some(/* address of buffer + bytes_transferred */
                         boost::bind(&myClass::handle_read, shared_from_this(),
                              boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }
}
```

I know this example would work for only one call ( then I would have to save the alread transferred bytes in another variable ) but I just wanted to make my point clear.

So anyone has some help how I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use async_read with a header that contain data size. Then call again async_read with the read size. I just give some exemples on other post, just [take a look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336010/how-to-read-a-fix-sized-packet-using-boost-asio).

Answer (score 0):

Technically, boost::array has c_array() member function that allows you to access the underlying c-array. So you can write something like `asio::buffer(buffer.c_array() + bytesTransferred, buffer.size() - bytesTransferred))`

But it would be more safe to use `asio::streambuf`.